# Update KPI Lists Script

Tags: list, powershell

I have about 400 KPI lists, and an error in one of the KPIs on each list. Is there a way I can update all of the lists automatically? I cannot use .NET, but a shell script is within an acceptable range.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: You can use powershell, the script depends heavily on the type of update/change you want to do. Are you able to give more information in that regards?

Comment: @hugh thanks for the reply, we will need to update the KPIs to go from higher values are good, warning at 20, green at 26, to lower values are good, warning at 1, red at 6. I believe we decided that moving forward our client will have to handle the changes themselves.